# Use Forge to Access Change Report from BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to use Forge with some BIM 360 API to gain access to the changes in a model from one version to the next?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API available for doing BIM360 model comparison on Forge currently. However, here are two workarounds you might be interested in:

1. Compare changes via Forge Viewer: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/comparing-versions-viewer
2. [Dump changes via Revit Addin](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/01/tracking-element-modification.html), and then integrate its results with Forge.

Comment: Thank you Eason. That answers my question. While the BIM 360 Viewer is a great visual tool, I shall be monitoring the relevant elements in some fashion as discussed by Jeremy Tammic.Kind Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0):

What you can do though is to leverage Webhook to get notified when a new version is “upserted” to the Data Management API. See docs here:

- Official Doc: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-data-management/
- Sample Code: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/webhooks-and-bim-360-c

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am needing to monitor a few thiusand rooms, say, and instead of doing that with Dynamo and Python, I was hoping that the BIM 360 API  could do the work for me. Kind Regards, Paul